# Android aar file dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, aar

My goal is to distribute an **.aar** file that can be used by other developers in their projects. The problem I find is when I try integrate my **.aar** into other project, is I need specify all of the dependencies in their **build.gradle** file that I have already included in my **.aar build.gradle**.

My question is if it's possible to only include my library as a dependency and somehow the libraries that my library depends on will get included in the other project.

Answer (score 1):

If you distribute your AAR through an artifact repository, you can also distribute dependency information. In the case of a Maven-style repository — the most popular kind nowadays — that dependency information is part of the POM file that would be published with the AAR. You can use established repositories (e.g., JCenter, Maven Central) or roll your own (as Google did with `maven.google.com` and what I do on Amazon S3 with `repo.commonsware.com`).

If, instead, you insist upon distributing the AAR as a plain file, then you have no means of distributing dependency information, other than via documentation. This is no different than distributing JARs.